# Is it ok to turn off `#IfWin` context sensitivity with `#If`?

Tags: windows, automation, autohotkey

Quoting from [#IfWinActive / #IfWinNotActive / #IfWinExist / #IfWinNotExist](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm#Basic_Operation)
:

> To turn off context-sensitivity, specify any #IfWin directive but omit all of its parameters. For example:
>
> ```
> #IfWinActive
> ```

Do we have to use `#IfWin` to close `#IfWin`? I found that `#If` seems to do the job as well, but it's not documented.

If you're curious why I'd like to close `#IfWin` with `#If`, that's because my code is like the following:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe App.exe
  #c::
  Esc::WinClose
#If WinExist("ahk_exe App.exe")
  #c::WinActivate ahk_exe App.exe
#If
  #c::Call("App.exe")
#If
```

So it makes more sense to use `#If` to close.

Comment: There are several caveats to the #If directive. See [doku](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm#General_Remarks).
Therefore replace `#If WinActive`, `#If WinExist` etc. by `#IfWinActive`, `#IfWinExist`  etc. whenever possible and turn off context sensitivity using `#IfWinActive`  etc.

Comment: @user3419297 Thanks! You can post an answer for that.

Comment: @user3419297 By "doku", you meant "document", right?

Comment: Because you can have a lot of hot keys or hot strings in a script, the #IfWinActive directive can be helpful for a batch of hot strings which will only be used for typo fixes (so active for Notepad, or some such, only). Use #IfWinActive, {WinName} at start of batch, and #IfWinActive at end of batch. Hope that makes sense.